# How to fetch query using function in hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I need to generate the following query using criteria.. how to do?

```
select worker_id,date_format(date,'%m-%Y'),sum(SalaryPerDay),sum(attendance) from tbl_attendance
where worker_id is not null and  date_format(date,'%m-%Y') = date_format(now(),'%m-%Y')
group by worker_id, date_format(date,'%m-%Y')
order by date,worker_id

public class Attendance  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4917788836066742576L;
    private Integer attendanceId;
    private Date date;
    private Integer workerId;
    private Integer vehicleId;
    private Integer salaryId;
    private Double salaryPerDay;
    private Double attendance;
    private Double startingTime;
    private Double closingTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database but `date_format` will probably not be supported out of the box by Hibernate.
If you truly want it done via Criteria you will,probably, need to implement your own [Criterion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) for comparison and [Projection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projection.html) for `group by`.

You could also use HQL with custom dialect that you will need to implement to support `date_format`

It seems that you may be better off writing native SQL query here. Hibernate offers all you need for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would probably not use criteria for this. Criteria is useful when the query must be dynamically generated based on variable search criteria. Your query is completely static, doesn't return entities but scalars, and you already have it. Why not just using a SQL query? Or at least a HQL query if you don't want to hard-code table and column names.

If criteria, for some obscure reason, is the only accepted way to execute this query, I would not format the result of the query in SQL. I would do it in Java, which would at least make the select and group by clauses easier to generate.

The only hard thing left is the date format. But wait, your query select rows which must all be in the current month. All the returned rows will have the same formatted date. So, why selecting it in the first place?

So in fact, your query could be rewritten as is:

```
select worker_id ,sum(SalaryPerDay), sum(attendance) from tbl_attendance
where worker_id is not null 
and date >= :startOfCurrentMonth, 
and date < :endOfNextMonth
group by worker_id
order by worker_id
```

And suddenly, it becomes simple to execute, in HQL or Criteria.

Comment: This query will return records for every date. but i need to group it for month.

Comment: Your original query groups by worker and month, but is only interested in a single month (the current month). So in fact, it groups by worker, and so does my query.